# how do I give leading and trailing space first and last colllectionview cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` and I want to give leading space to first `collectionView` cell and not for the rest of the one and I want to give trailing space to last `collectionView` cell.

I can give leading and trialing space to `collectionView` as whole but I don't know how to do for individual cells like this

I couldn't think of a way to do this.

Help please

Comment: you can use `collectionViewLayout` to add leading space and trailing space.

Comment: can you give me code snippet to do that please

Answer (score 3):

You can keep a constraint of leading space, and make an outlet of it.

Keep the constraint as default 0 for all cells.

If the cell is first, `indexpath.row = 0` or `indexpath.row = count - 1`, at those times, change the `contraint.constant` to whatever you need.

Don't forget to call `layoutIfNeeded`.